# Diifference between copied and moved vm?

Tags: vmware-player

When ever I copy virtual machine directory, I get challenged by the vmware-player - Did I more or copy?

What/Why is the difference?

Comment: The difference is well documented... [as is our FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq), which I think you should visit.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, a Move maintains the VM UUID while a copy will generate a new UUID.